# For loop not sending value while making http call

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the below code to iterate through an excel column and use the retrieved values when making an http POST call, but while I'm able to print all of the extracted values.. I'm struggling as the http call only sends the last index of the iteration.

```
def createChannel():
    url = "http://hostname/createjson/"

    for row in ws.iter_cols(min_row=2, min_col=1, max_row=4, max_col=1):
        #print("Channels")
            for cell in row:
                #print int(cell.value)
                channelName = cell.value

                print(channelName)

                payload2 = {"name": channelName,"details": {"test": "adad"}}

                json_str = json.dumps(payload2, indent=True)

                headers = {
                'content-type': "application/json",
                'cache-control': "no-cache",
                'postman-token': "6247f803-25e8-2f9d-2a6e-0dc98b54a483"
                }

                response = requests.request("POST", url, data=json_str, headers=headers)
                print(response.text)

createChannel()
```

This prints:

```
CNN
TBS
TNT
{"id":"5463463553","name":"TNT","details":{"test":"adad"}}
```

I'm wondering what is it wrong with the code that only sends the last value when executing the POST call.. I'm expecting that when I print the response for each call, I would print the json response for each channel. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can simplify the request a little bit like so: `requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload2)`.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a response for the other channel names?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the code is only making 1 call using the last value but I want to make 3 calls as I'm retrieving 3 values from the excel sheet.

Comment: What does `json_str` look like for each name?